# joomla jomfish customization

Tags: joomla

I need to place jomfish language change module inside my component is there a easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the loadposition plugin? This is installed in Joomla by default.

Comment: but I would like to customize it a liitle bit, just need flags with links thats it.

Comment: That's easily done. You should be able to override the module output to create your own output. You can then use CSS to display the correct image. This page uses a similar technique. Take a look at the html and CSS. http://www.woweeone.com/index.php/uk/component/content/article/51